# Many-to-many unidirectional issue with query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm facing some troubles with a query that I want to do in a many to many relationship

I have two entities : Site and Language

Site is the owner side so I have :

```
class Site 
{
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Language", cascade={"persist"})
    */
   protected $languages;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->languages = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   public function getLanguages()
   {
      return $this->languages;
   }

   public function setLanguages($languages)
   {
      $this->languages = $languages;

      return $this;
   }
}
```

Language entity :

```
class Language
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    ... (getters and setters)

}
```

In a twig template I display all the sites. 
And I want to add a new column with the languages of each sites but I don't know what request I can do to get this...

**In summary, what request I have to do to get all the languages of a site ??**

**EDIT** : my action which sends data to twig template :

```
public function indexListSiteAction()
        {
            $repository = $this->get('doctrine')
                ->getRepository('BackBundle:Site');

            if (!$repository) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Site entity.');
            }

            $sites = $repository->findAll();

            return $this->render('BackBundle:Site:site_list.html.twig', array(
                'sites'       => $sites,
            ));
        }
```

Comment: Can you post you're controller code who send the data to the twig template ?

Comment: I edit my answer, you can look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `$languages` in your template very easily.

You would do something like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for element in entity.languages %}
        <li>{{ element.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I recommend reading the [documentation about loops](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) in **Twig**.

Comment: I know that. But I don't know what request can I do to get all the languages ​​of a site, that is my question

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Once you've got your `Site` entity in the view you can do what I've shown above.